# How to get the first name from the list

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a values file like:

```
secrets:
  file.tst |
    {
      content ....
    }
```

And I would like to get file.tst name in the yaml template. I already tried with:

```
{{ .Values.secrets.secrets |trimSuffix "-" }}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Is `.Values.secrets | keys | first` what you're after?  Or do you need to look inside the content somehow?

Comment: Hi David. Thanks it works for me!

Comment: Just another question, if I'll have more files like this file.tst - can I get them from the range? And how I can create "if" statement to check number of files in the list? Regards!, Michael

Answer (score 1):

With that `values.yaml` layout, `.Values.secrets` is itself a dictionary, with string keys and string values.  Helm includes [many functions](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/) that can operate on details of these.  In particular, you can call [`keys`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#keys) to get the keys of a dictionary as a list, and [`first`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#first-mustfirst) to get the first item out of a list.

```yaml
firstFilename: "{{ .Values.secrets | keys | first }}"
```

You can also use the built-in `range` function to iterate over either the map itself or the list of keys.

```yaml
hashes:
{{- $filename, $contents := range .Values.secrets }}
  {{ $filename }}: "{{ sha256sum $contents }}"
{{- end }}
```